# GStreamer Tutorials - Unknown type name 'time_t'

Tags: gstreamer

I installed GStreamer from https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-mac-osx.html?gi-language=c and then downloaded the tutorials from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-docs/

Opening up the tutorials in XCode and running them yields:

```
Unknown type name 'time_t'; did you mean 'size_t'?
```

I think I might be missing a small step here like the wrong libraries are linked or something. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue of another header file with the same name (from libavutil in GStreamer) being imported before the system `time.h`. Setting "Always Search User Paths" to "No" in the project's Build Settings did not help, I had to manually insert system path, in my case `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys`, before the GStreamer paths into "Header Search Paths" box. There's probably a better way

Comment: Confirming that this did it for me. Alternatively that/equivalent path prefixing time.h at the top of the tutorial does work, but is probably an even worse way :D (NB: did have to add the library search paths (eg. /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Libraries/**)  as per the "new project" instructions at the Gstreamer site).

Comment: Also, this will play the file but not pop up the window, you'll only hear sound. You'll need to set up a run loop to actually see the popup...